# Как вывести в отдельный столбец промежуточное значение из строки?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как в отдельную таблицу выписать N-e по счету значение из упорядоченной по одному столбцу другой таблицы? Объясню на примере:

**Предположим, есть таблица T**:

*Товар | Магазин | Цена*

Хлеб | Монетка | 3

Хлеб | У Захара | 7

Хлеб | Алёнка | 8

Молоко | Монетка | 10

Сало | Монетка | 15

Хлеб | Магнит | 4

Сало | У Захара | 16

**Нужно получить запросом таблицу:**

*Товар | Второй по дороговизне магазин | цена*

Хлеб | Магнит | 4

Сало | У Захара | 16

Молоко | NULL | NULL

Можно еще добавить два столбца "третий по дороговизне магазин" и "цена", но, думаю, вопрос уже становится понятным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нумеруем записи в нужном разрезе и порядке и получаем вторые. Но необходимость строки с NULL в случае отсутствия второй цены усложняет задачу, надо так же получать записи в случае если количество в группе равно 1. Поэтому получаем количество, на выводе его анализируем и даем значения из колонок только если это количество больше 1.

```
select product,
       case when cnt>1 then market end,
       case when cnt>1 then price end
  from (
    select product, market, price,
           row_number() over(partition by product order by price) RN,
           count(1) over(partition by product) cnt
      from T
  ) X
  where RN=2 OR CNT=1
```